# RoR AngularJS, html.erb in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

Quick question, been searching can't find a definite answer.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but for example in my routes I have a 
.when('/something', {templateUrl: 'something/in/public/folder/list.html.erb')

It works but the ruby code in html.erb isn't interpreted.

Is that how it works, or am I missing something where ruby code is able to be interpreted in that templateUrl.

just shows up as

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can put only static content in public folder, like plain html, css, javascript, images. Embedded ruby code wont be executed.

`.erb` files go under `app/views/` directory

Comment: Would it make sense to put angularjs view files in the views directory? I wasn't able to link to it in angularjs.

Comment: @pk1m I have all my angular views in app/views